# $Pr(X>Y)<0.5$ iff $E(X)<E(Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For any real-valued continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ which have unimodal distributions, is the following statement true?
$$Pr(X>Y)<1/2$$ 
 $$iff$$
$$E(X)<E(Y)$$
I have the PDFs of both distributions so I can formulate $Pr(X>Y)$, however the expression is very complex so I would like a short-cut by just examining the means. In actuality, $X$ is a half-normal and $Y$ is a folded-normal.

Comment: Looking at $Z=X-Y$, this is the same as asking "is $E[Z]<0$ equivalent to $P(Z>0)<\frac 12$".  But consider $Z=-10^9$ with probability $.1$ and $Z=1$ with probability $.9$.

Comment: Yeah, definitely look at the discrete case first - it becomes much clearer there that this is not true.